# How to repaint window after hide or show control

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a NSTextField control on the bottom of the window.
I need to show them or hide according to some condition.

In the initial state the control is hidden.
The window shows the blank space on the control's position.
When in runtime the control should become visible

```
mpTxtCtrl.hidden = NO;
```

it does not happen.

The tasks:

1 Display/Hide control.

2 Resize the main window according to the control's state.

I can't find any tutorials how to manage layouts in the cocoa.
I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: What is your control? check box, radio etc?

Comment: Anoop Vaidya, no i do not use autolayout. I'm new in MacOs programming. Please, give me a link to appropriate tutorial. The target control - is a text field (NSTextField).

Answer (score 1):

> When in runtime the control should become visible
>
> ```
> mpTxtCtrl.hidden = NO;
> ```
>
> it does not happen.

Make sure you connected the `mpTxtCtrl` outlet to the text field in your nib. Having forgotten to connect your outlet to anything is a leading cause of nothing happening.

> I can't find any tutorials how to manage layouts in the cocoa.

Switch to the File Inspector while editing the nib and turn “Use Auto Layout” on. Xcode will create constraints whenever you place views along Aqua guides (the blue lines that appear when you place and size views correctly), and Cocoa will enforce these constraints as the sizes of views and the window change.

More info:

- [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)
- [WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) — include several sessions on Auto Layout
- [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/) — Aqua guide lines appear to indicate conformance to the HIG

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer. I will study the proposed guidelines in more detail, and I think that they will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, if you will find some useful stuffs [here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6013591/showhidemaximise-36k?da=y):

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [self.label setHidden:YES];
}


- (IBAction)showHide:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",[sender title]);

    if ([[sender title] isEqualToString:@"Hide"]) {
        [self.label setHidden:YES];
        [sender setTitle:@"Show"];
    }
    else if ([[sender title] isEqualToString:@"Show"]){
        [self.label setHidden:NO];
        [sender setTitle:@"Hide"];

    }

}

- (IBAction)maximize:(id)sender {

    NSArray *screens = [NSScreen screens];
    NSRect screenRect;
    for (NSInteger index=0; index < [screens count]; index++) {
        NSScreen *screen = screens[index];
        screenRect = [screen visibleFrame];
    }
    [self.window setFrame:screenRect display:YES];
}
```

Comment: So, what's the questioner's problem, and how does this lump of code solve it?

Comment: @PeterHosey: He needs to hide / show a control at runtime. and even resize the window.

Comment: That's his goal, not the problem he's having achieving it.